# incorrect nextPageToken Bug in Google Classroom API V1

Tags: google-classroom

When asking for a list of courses (or any list), if the list is empty a nextPageToken is still returned, there may be a very good reason for this, but maybe not.  It makes it seem like there is still more information to get.  I message saying "no more items" or something would be more useful.

I think is happening because we had a lot of courses, then they were all deleted.

I used this page to help test.
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue that although deleted courses aren't returned in a response, they still use up spots in the response, sometimes leading to sparse or empty pages of results. In this case however the `nextPageToken` is actually correct, as there may be non-deleted courses returned after the first page. The paging logic should always be that you continue to fetch pages until the `nextPageToken` field is missing, regardless of how many items are returned in the response.

Comment: Is this still an issue?  I'm handling it in my code, but it would be nice if there weren't multiple round-trip-time delays.