# courses.list google classroom API returns JSON that doesn't match the API description

Tags: google-api-js-client, google-classroom

We've had a report from a user that things weren't working correctly in our google classroom integration. After poking around for a bit, we had the user send their HAR file with all the network information for when they use our API. In it we found that the request we make:

```
 gapi.client.request({
   root: 'https://classroom.googleapis.com',
   path: 'v1/courses',
   params: {
     'pageSize': 1,
     'teacherId': 'me'
   }
 })
```

gets back a response with the nextPageToken property set but no courses property set.

Below is the actual entry from the HAR file (minus the Authorization header):

```
{
    "startedDateTime": "2016-03-25T21:08:16.672Z",
    "time": 957.9219999995985,
    "request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://content-classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?pageSize=1&teacherId=me",
      "httpVersion": "unknown",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable",
          "value": "base64"
        },
        {
          "name": "X-Origin",
          "value": "https://www.lucidpress.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "X-ClientDetails",
          "value": "appVersion=5.0%20(X11%3B%20CrOS%20x86_64%207834.61.0)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F49.0.2623.95%20Safari%2F537.36&platform=Linux%20x86_64&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(X11%3B%20CrOS%20x86_64%207834.61.0)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F49.0.2623.95%20Safari%2F537.36"
        },
        {
          "name": "User-Agent",
          "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 7834.61.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.95 Safari/537.36"
        },
        {
          "name": "Referer",
          "value": "https://content-classroom.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?sensitive_query_string?"
        },
        {
          "name": "X-JavaScript-User-Agent",
          "value": "google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0-beta"
        },
        {
          "name": "X-Referer",
          "value": "https://www.lucidpress.com"
        }
      ],
      "queryString": [
        {
          "name": "pageSize",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "teacherId",
          "value": "me"
        }
      ],
      "cookies": [],
      "headersSize": -1,
      "bodySize": 0
    },
    "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "statusText": "",
      "httpVersion": "unknown",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "date",
          "value": "Fri, 25 Mar 2016 21:08:18 GMT"
        },
        {
          "name": "content-encoding",
          "value": "gzip"
        },
        {
          "name": "x-content-type-options",
          "value": "nosniff"
        },
        {
          "name": "server",
          "value": "ESF"
        },
        {
          "name": "x-frame-options",
          "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
        },
        {
          "name": "vary",
          "value": "Origin"
        },
        {
          "name": "vary",
          "value": "X-Origin"
        },
        {
          "name": "vary",
          "value": "Referer"
        },
        {
          "name": "content-type",
          "value": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        {
          "name": "status",
          "value": "200"
        },
        {
          "name": "alternate-protocol",
          "value": "443:quic,p=1"
        },
        {
          "name": "cache-control",
          "value": "private"
        },
        {
          "name": "alt-svc",
          "value": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"31,30,29,28,27,26,25\""
        },
        {
          "name": "content-length",
          "value": "198"
        },
        {
          "name": "x-xss-protection",
          "value": "1; mode=block"
        }
      ],
      "cookies": [],
      "content": {
        "size": 206,
        "mimeType": "application/json",
        "text": "{\n  \"nextPageToken\": \"some_string_token_sensitive?"\n}\n"
      },
      "redirectURL": "",
      "headersSize": -1,
      "bodySize": -1,
      "_transferSize": 448
    },
    "cache": {},
    "timings": {
      "blocked": 2.4730000004638,
      "dns": -1,
      "connect": -1,
      "send": 0.8660000003146702,
      "wait": 953.5609999984446,
      "receive": 1.0220000003754421,
      "ssl": -1
    }
  },
```

I've had the user fill in the request through the "Try it!" area in the [api description](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list#request-body) without pageSize set to 1 and it gives back the correct format. We've also been unable to reproduce with our test accounts and we aren't hearing any other reports of similar issues.

Has anyone else run into this or have any ideas of what might be happening?

Comment: I know this doesn't address the *missing* courses property, but it explains why there may be no results when you are expecting some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567498

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about the JSON response is imporoperly formatted. `pageSize` sets the maximum number of results that the API should return, not the minimum. Your code should handle the case where `nextPageToken` is set but `courses` is not by retrieving the next page until it gets a course back.

Out of curiosity, why are you only retrieving a single course to begin with?

Comment: The API says that the response will have courses as an array. It sounds like what you're saying is the API is wrong or am I just reading it incorrectly? I'd like to know so I don't make the same mistake with other API's.

Comment: We're just asking for one course because we're interested in knowing if the individual is a teacher in any course.

Comment: Sorry just realized the title is very misleading. I'm going to change that. I didn't mean to say it's not valid JSON but that it doesn't match the API description.

Comment: By the way, now that I'm a little more awake. Thanks for taking some time to look at my question.